# Function in MySQL that operates on multiple columns

Tags: mysql, database

Is it possible to create a custom function in MySQL like SUM, MAX, and so on. That accepts multiple columns and do some operation on each row?

The reason I am asking this question is because I tried to do my logic using stored procedure but unfortunatelly couldn't find a way how to select data from table name where the name of the table is input parameter.

Somebody suggested to use dynamic SQL but I can not get the cursor. So my only hope is to use custom defined function.

To make the question more clear here is what I want to do:

I want to calculate the distance of a route where each row in the database table represents coordinates (latitude and longtitude). Unfortunatelly the data I have is really big and if I query the data and do the calculationgs using Java it takes more than half a minute to transfer the data to the web server so I want to do the calculations on the SQL machine.

Comment: Is there a reason why you cannot process the data after you retrieved it?

Comment: _“like SUM, MAX and so on..”_ – what exactly is “and so on”? For SUM it would be quite easy to just SUM up per column and add those sums together, and the maximum of several MAX values could be determined using GREATEST() … and what a cursor has to do with this and how it’s a problem is quite unclear to me.

Comment: It sounds like you may want to [create a stored function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/create-function.html), but without further detail it's impossible to be certain...

Comment: i have a database tables with milions of rows representing gps coordinates of vehicles' routes. So instead of quering all the data from a table ( it takes more than 30 seconds ) and compute the distance i want to be able to do the math on the mysql server. Unfortunatelly the stored procedures does not all to use a a table name on the fly (Select something1, something2 from table_name where table name is a variable) so i am looking for another solution.

Answer (score 0):

> Select something1, something2 from table_name where table name is a variable

Multiple identically-structured tables (prerequisite for this sort of query) is contrary to the [Principle of Orthogonal Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_Orthogonal_Design).

**Don't do it**.  At least not without *very* good reason—with suitable indexes, (tens of) millions of records per table is easily enough for MySQL to handle without any need for partitioning; and even if one *does* need to partition the data, there are [better ways](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/partitioning.html) than this manual kludge (which can give rise to ambiguous, potentially inconsistent data and lead to redundancy and complexity in your data manipulation code).

Comment: i don't know if you understand me but i do not want to wait 30 seconds to select all data and then to compute it just to get a single double value!

Comment: @JoroSeksa: Yes, I understand you.  I think that you don't understand me.  I'm telling you that your current schema is *a bad idea* and that you should instead invest in suitably *indexing* your data and/or *natively* partitioning your tables as required.  Since your question does not contain any specifics upon which one can give concrete instruction, you will have to research these ideas yourself and come back if you have questions about how to implement them.

Comment: Please don't tell me some teoretical ideas. No matter what you do or optimise the problem is that when you query big data over the network things get really slowly so the only solution is to do the calculations on the sql server and get only the result you need

Comment: @JoroSeksa: I completely agree.  Which is why *indexing* and/or *native partitioning* (both of which are optimisations in the database layer) are invaluable tools in your arsenal.  I have now recommended them three times.  I shan't continue keep going round in circles on this point, lest the repeated union of this brick wall with my cranium lead to some permanent damage.